# how to selectively pass columns or rows of a 2D array to a function?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

i have an array of MAC addresses (char [6]) and want to select which one I pass on to a function but get a bit confused how to differentiate between columns & rows.
I've come up wit this for an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char mac_t[6];

void mac_print(mac_t mac);

int main(void) {

    mac_t macs[3]={0};
    //mac1
    macs[0][0]=0x00;
    macs[1][0]=0x00;
    macs[2][0]=0x00;
    macs[3][0]=0x00;
    macs[4][0]=0x00;
    macs[5][0]=0x00;

    //mac2
    macs[0][1]=0x01;
    macs[1][1]=0x01;
    macs[2][1]=0x01;
    macs[3][1]=0x01;
    macs[4][1]=0x01;
    macs[5][1]=0x01;

    //mac3
    macs[0][2]=0x02;
    macs[1][2]=0x02;
    macs[2][2]=0x02;
    macs[3][2]=0x02;
    macs[4][2]=0x02;
    macs[5][2]=0x02;

    mac_print(*(macs));
    mac_print(*(macs+1));
    mac_print(*(macs+2));

}


void mac_print(mac_t mac) {
        printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]);
}
```

How do I print mac1, mac2 & mac3 in function `mac-print` assuming the type `mac_t` is required?

Answer (score 2):

You just discovered why this:

```
typedef unsigned char mac_t[6];
```

is bad. Why? Because mac_t is an array. Look at this:

```
void mac_print(mac_t mac);
```

What do you think it means? It is a function which takes a `mac_t` type? Not really, it translates to taking a pointer.

```
// all forms mean the same
void mac_print(mac_t mac);
void mac_print(unsigned char mac[6]);
void mac_print(unsigned char mac[]);
void mac_print(unsigned char *mac);
```

because arrays declaration inside function parameter-list are adjusted into a pointer type, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) and [here](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7).

The best way to fix your code is with a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char v[6];
} mac_t;
```

Now you know what `mac_t` is. And you will also know how to index it. You also can do assignment `mac_t a; mac_t b; a = b;` and comparison `!memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(a))` easily (the memcmp needs a little training, but one can get used to it).

Try this:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char v[6];
} mac_t;

void mac_print(mac_t mac);

int main(void) {

    mac_t macs[3]={0};
    //mac1
    macs[0].v[0]=0x00;
    macs[0].v[1]=0x00;
    macs[0].v[2]=0x00;
    macs[0].v[3]=0x00;
    macs[0].v[4]=0x00;
    macs[0].v[5]=0x00;

    //mac2
    macs[1].v[0]=0x01;
    macs[1].v[1]=0x01;
    macs[1].v[2]=0x01;
    macs[1].v[3]=0x01;
    macs[1].v[4]=0x01;
    macs[1].v[5]=0x01;

    //mac3
    macs[2].v[0]=0x02;
    macs[2].v[1]=0x02;
    macs[2].v[2]=0x02;
    macs[2].v[3]=0x02;
    macs[2].v[4]=0x02;
    macs[2].v[5]=0x02;

    // we pass by value here, but it would be better to pass a pointer
    // ie. `void mac_print(mac_t *mac);` and `mac_print(&macs[0]);`
    mac_print(macs[0]);
    mac_print(macs[1]);
    mac_print(macs[2]);

}


void mac_print(mac_t mac) {
        printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",mac.v[0],mac.v[1],mac.v[2],mac.v[3],mac.v[4],mac.v[5]);
}
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go.

Comment: Point of detail: there is no VLA in the OP's code that I can see, not within the meaning of the term.

Comment: You are right, I was always confused by the wording in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array). Looked at the standard in [C11 6.7.6.2.4.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2) and it is clear `If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type`. So it is not VLA, you are right! Both in function prototype `''array of type'' shall be adjusted to ''qualified pointer to type''`.

Answer (score 1):

Should have been:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char mac_t[6];

void mac_print(mac_t mac);

int main(void) {

    mac_t macs[3]={0};
    //mac1
    macs[0][0]=0x00;
    macs[0][1]=0x00;
    macs[0][2]=0x00;
    macs[0][3]=0x00;
    macs[0][4]=0x00;
    macs[0][5]=0x00;

    //mac2
    macs[1][0]=0x01;
    macs[1][1]=0x01;
    macs[1][2]=0x01;
    macs[1][3]=0x01;
    macs[1][4]=0x01;
    macs[1][5]=0x01;

    //mac3
    macs[2][0]=0x02;
    macs[2][1]=0x02;
    macs[2][2]=0x02;
    macs[2][3]=0x02;
    macs[2][4]=0x02;
    macs[2][5]=0x02;

    mac_print(macs[0]);
    mac_print(macs[1]);
    mac_print(macs[2]);

}


void mac_print(mac_t mac) {
        printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3],mac[4],mac[5]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual definition of you "macs" variable in English is:

```
An array with three slots of arrays with six slots.
```

Your current usage assumes a definition of:

```
An array with six slots of arrays with three slots.
```

Therefore the dimensions of your array are really 3 by 6 and not 6 by 3 (as currently used).

This initializer may help build a more solid mental model:

```
mac_t macs[3] = 
{
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
    { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01},
    { 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02},
};
```

Finally, the printf statement requires a bit more work, as you are currently referencing slots of arrays (only 1 index specified) as opposed to the individual bytes in the array of arrays.